# HTML Form refuses to email in action="mailto:someaddress@gmail.com"

Tags: html, forms, gmail

So I tried even the w3schools email tutorial on this and replaced the placeholder email with my own and it didn't email my own gmail address.

Is this a new security feature??

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" 
enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant send emails only with HTML. This will only open Outlook or some other email client. The easiest way to send emails is to learn PHP and play with mail() too but you will need SMTP so it can work locally.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make **mailto** work, you need to define some kind of handler for that. Handlers are the application which will be use to send mail to the respective email address. if you have **GMAIL** account, then logged into your account on chrome and follow steps mentioned in [this](https://www.process.st/how-to-make-gmail-your-default-mail-client/) link, to make gmail your handler and then try to play with it.

But if you are thinking of using **mailto** function in your application for sending email then, it will not be good to tell users to change their settings in order to send email to your site.